# Singtel vs Starhub / M1 restrictions for a website login -

Tags: php, web

we are facing a very curious issue regarding website login of our "work in progress" application.

Our website app is currently under development and is hosted on a staging server in Australia. It is an account based setup and when we are trying to use the website on a Singtel network in Singapore, we are experiencing automatic log-out's, PHP errors, etc etc while we don't face any issues while using a Starhub or M1 network.

I'm not very technical myself but was keen to understand if anyone can guide me and / or my technical team as to why such an issue can occur over different ISP's and how to resolve this problem.

Appreciate any insights that you may have.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the PHP errors? Are you using IP address as one of the validations in session/cookie?

Comment: Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: core/Base_Controller.php
Line Number: 440
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/transaction.php
Line Number: 58

Comment: the above is a PHP error that comes up when we click on one of the buttons post logging into the account... however when we do click on some of the other buttons, then we are logged out automatically...

Comment: and this issue occurs only while using a Singtel network... it does not crop up while using a Starhub connection... to be honest I havent yet tested using M1... I am also not sure whether this is an ISP related issue... and unfortunately the outsourced web development i am using are clueless about this as it is working fine for them on their networks

Comment: I'm guessing it's a bug causing the logout and not really a network issue. Try checking the codes around the line numbers that are throwing the errors.

Comment: but what could be the reason that this bug seems to be in effect only on a singtel network mate... i tested the app at home (starhub) and at work (singtel)... i never face the issue at home, only at work... so i am bit keen to understand if there are any ISP specific settings that would trigger such an error?

Comment: Without looking at the code, no one can tell what could be the reason. Post the code if possible.